# Extracting Map values from a Custom Mule Transfomer

Tags: mule

How can I extract the values from a java.util.Map returned from a custom transformer which performs  some functions on JSON data and returns the results in a map.

```
public class MyTransformer extends AbstractTransformer{
 public Map<String,Object> doTransform(Object src,..){
  return myMap;  
}
```

I want to use the values returned in a JdbcConnector query parameters like so :

```
<jdbc-query key="myQuery" value="insert in dataTbl values(mapKey1,mapKey2...)"> etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MEL:

```
#[message.payload.key]
```

in your JDBC query values.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to specify constants to use as keys in the flow?

Comment: You could do: `#[message.payload[com.acme.MyConstants.MY_KEY]]`